# Dynamic resizing of LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid Items Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What I am trying to achieve is once an item is selected three things should happened:

The first being the background color changes.
The selected item resizes and becomes larger.
and neighboring items become slightly smaller

[image of what I looking to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d79Jd.png)

The only thing I have tried so far is the following

```
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(100.dp)
)
```

inside the item composable I have the following snippets of code responsible for resizing:

```
var size by remember {
    mutableStateOf(125.dp)
}

size = if(isSelected){
    150.dp
} else{
    125.dp
}
```

I knew that the items above and below would not change but I was hoping the items left and right would

Comment: I'm not sure it will work out of the box since it will always try to keep the items with the minimum width specified. Have you looked at this though: https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/1630f6b35ac9e25fb3cd3a64208d7c9afaaaedc5/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/example/owl/ui/courses/FeaturedCourses.kt#L161 ?  Going for a custom layout and measuring the children should do the trick